# Cargo bike brick identity

Tags: part-identification, building, snot

Looking to identify the box pieces here:

[image]

Comment: The creator of that cargo bike shared [full instructions](https://mobile.twitter.com/URBLR/status/1057247320310349825?cxt=HHwWgoCo7cK1jKwdAAAA) on his twitter account.

Answer (score 22):

That's not a single part.

According to the instructions [shared by the creator of that cargo bike on their twitter account](https://mobile.twitter.com/URBLR/status/1057247320310349825?cxt=HHwWgoCo7cK1jKwdAAAA), it's a combination of :

- 1 [Black Plate, Round 1 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4073&name=Plate,%20Round%201%20x%201&category=%5BPlate,%20Round%5D#T=C&C=11)

[image]

- 1 [Black Plate, Modified 2 x 3 with Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3176&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

[image]

- 2 [Black Bracket 1 x 2 - 2 x 2 Inverted](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99207&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

[image]

- 1 [Black Panel 1 x 2 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4865&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

[image]

- 2 [Black Tile, Round 1 x 1 Quarter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=25269&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

[image]

- 2 [Black Tile 1 x 2 with Groove](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3069b&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

[image]

- 2 [Black Tile 1 x 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=63864&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

[image]

- 2 [Black Bracket 1 x 2 - 1 x 2 Inverted](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99780&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

[image]

- 1 [Light Bluish Gray Plate, Modified 2 x 2 Thin with Plane Single Wheel Holder](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2415&idColor=86#T=C&C=86)

[image]

- 1 [Trans-Clear Wheel Center Small with Stub Axles (Pulley Wheel)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3464&idColor=12#T=C&C=12)

[image]

- 1 [Black Tire 14mm D. x 4mm Smooth Small Single](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3139&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

[image]

Comment: I'd give extra point for finding building instructions.

Comment: He did!  See the comments on the question.  Bravo Sander.